# How to use array reduce with condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, computed-properties

So I have an array

```
const records = [
    {
        value: 24,
        gender: "BOYS"
    },
    {
        value: 42,
        gender: "BOYS"
    },
    {
        value: 85,
        gender: "GIRLS"
    },
    {
        value: 12,
        gender: "GIRLS"
    },
    {
        value: 10,
        gender: "BOYS"
    }
]
```

And I want to get the `sum` so I used the JavaScript array reduce function and got it right. Here is my code:

```
someFunction() {
  return records.reduce(function(sum, record){
    return sum + record.value; 
  }, 0);
}
```

With that code I get the value `173` which is correct. Now what I wanted to do is to get all the sum only to those objects who got a `"BOYS"` gender.

I tried something like

```
someFunction() {
  return records.reduce(function(sum, record){
    if(record.gender == 'BOYS') return sum + record.value; 
  }, 0);
}
```

But I get nothing. Am I missing something here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

When you return nothing from the reduce function it returns undefined and undefined + 1 === NaN. You should instead filter the array before reducing.

```
records.filter(({gender}) => gender === 'BOYS')
    .reduce((sum, record) => sum + record.value)
```

Comment: This is the correct way, could you reformat the code into two lines

Comment: The correct way to do it. +1 for that but it doesn't explain the cause for the original bug. Instead it just eliminates it.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins It's because the items were added to undefined so he got NaN `(() => {})() + 1 === NaN`

Answer (score 24):

You need to return the current sum and not `undefined` if your condition is not matched.

Otherwise you aren't returning your accumulator to the reduce function and end up adding `unefined` + record.value when matched or `undefined` + `undefined` when it is not matched.

Try this:

```html
<script>
  const records = [{
      value: 24,
      gender: "BOYS"
    },
    {
      value: 42,
      gender: "BOYS"
    },
    {
      value: 85,
      gender: "GIRLS"
    },
    {
      value: 12,
      gender: "GIRLS"
    },
    {
      value: 10,
      gender: "BOYS"
    }
  ];

  function someFunction() {
    return records.reduce(function(sum, record) {
     return (record.gender !== 'BOYS') ? sum : sum + record.value;

    }, 0);
  }
  console.log(someFunction());
</script>
```

Answer (score 16):

If the gender is 'GIRLS' it will return undefined. Add an else statement that returns sum and it should fix the problem.

```js
const records = [
    {
        value: 24,
        gender: "BOYS"
    },
    {
        value: 42,
        gender: "BOYS"
    },
    {
        value: 85,
        gender: "GIRLS"
    },
    {
        value: 12,
        gender: "GIRLS"
    },
    {
        value: 10,
        gender: "BOYS"
    }
]

function someFunction() {
  return records.reduce(function(sum, record){
    if(record.gender == 'BOYS') return sum + record.value;
    else return sum;
  }, 0);
}

console.log(someFunction())
```

Answer (score 8):

You should also return the `sum` when the gender is `GIRLS`. `reduce` goes through each item and expects a `return` value. If you don't `return` a value, it will be `undefined`. So after the third iteration, the `sum` will be `undefined`.

```
const sumBoys = records.reduce((sum, record) => {
  if (record.gender.toLowerCase() === 'boys') {
    return sum + record.value;
  }

  return sum;
}, 0);
```

```js
const records = [{
  value: 24,
  gender: "BOYS"
}, {
  value: 42,
  gender: "BOYS"
}, {
  value: 85,
  gender: "GIRLS"
}, {
  value: 12,
  gender: "GIRLS"
}, {
  value: 10,
  gender: "BOYS"
}];

const sumBoys = records.reduce((sum, record) => {
  if (record.gender.toLowerCase() === 'boys') {
    return sum + record.value;
  }

  return sum;
}, 0);

console.log(sumBoys);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to retrieve which object is having gender is "BOYS". But some objects having Female gender at that time it will returns undefined.

Try this to avoid that undefined ....

```
var resSet=records.filter(function(options){
    return options.gender == "BOYS";
}).reduce(function(a,b){
    return a+parseInt(b.value);
},0);

console.log("the sum of boys set is --"+resSet);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, in case you just want to stick with `reduce` and don't want to use `filter`, you can do it this way:

```js
const records = [
    {
        value: 24,
        gender: "BOYS"
    },
    {
        value: 42,
        gender: "BOYS"
    },
    {
        value: 85,
        gender: "GIRLS"
    },
    {
        value: 12,
        gender: "GIRLS"
    },
    {
        value: 10,
        gender: "BOYS"
    }
];

  var res = records.reduce(function(sum, record){
    if(record.gender === 'BOYS') {
       return sum + record.value;
     } else{
        return sum
    }; 
  }, 0);
  console.log(res);
```

```
  var res = records.reduce(function(sum, record){
    if(record.gender == 'BOYS') {
       return sum + record.value;
     } else{
        return sum
    }; 
  }, 0);
```

Comment: This answer was given three years earlier

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that if `records` was empty you want to set an accumulator value that matches your output. Also the definition of empty when `records.length === 0` vs when only count of BOYS is 0 might be different.

```js
const defaultValue = 0, target = 'BOYS'
const result = records.reduce( (sum,{gender,value})=>{
   return gender === target ? (sum||0)+value : sum;
},defaultValue);
```

some fun with `reduce` and your question:
https://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/021axnsr/8/

Answer (score 1):

```
const data = records.reduce(function(sum, record){
if(record.gender == 'BOYS') 
    sum = sum+record.value;
    return sum; 
}, 0);

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use this simplified code

```
let res= records.reduce(function(a,b){ 
    return (b.gender === "BOYS" && (a+parseInt(b.value))) || a; 
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you got an error because, reduce method iterate.in each element i. array and returns the.accumulated value,

what happen is, when your condition did not meet, the value of accumulator becomes.undefined because you.did not return it.

you need to sum first if it meets the.condition.
and outside the if scope return the sum,

Answer (score 0):

Just use only [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and you can solve it by:

```
const test = records.reduce((a, e) => {
        if (e.gender === "BOYS") {
          return a + e.value;
        } else {
          return a;
        }
      }, 0);
      console.log(test);
```

Comment: Answer of the same style given [3 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62082000/5273255) on this same question