# Reduce method on array of objects with conditional

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, `data`, that I'm attempting to retrieve the total of both shoe sizes.

I'm having issues counting `"size 10"` apart from `"size 5"`. I've attempted to use the `.reduce()` method with a conditional to only add the total count if the names match:

```js
const data = [
    { "shoeSize": "size 10", "total": 9 },
    { "shoeSize": "size 10", "total": 3 },
    { "shoeSize": "size 5",  "total": 2 }
];

const grandTotal = data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return {
        shoeSize10Total: 
            prev.shoeSize === "size 10" || 
            curr.shoeSize === "size 10" && 
            prev.total + curr.total,

        shoeSize5Total: 
            prev.shoeSize === "size 5" || 
            curr.shoeSize === "size 5" && 
            prev.total + curr.total
    };
});

console.log(grandTotal);
```

However, the result of this method returns `NaN` and `false` - instead of the total amount of numbers for each.

I've tried looking up a solution and found something similar on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204270/how-to-use-array-reduce-with-condition-in-javascript), but they are filtering to return the value of 1; I would like to return both in an object.

This is the intended result of my `.reduce()`:

```
const grandTotal = {
    shoeSize10Total: 12
    shoeSize5Total: 2
};
```

Comment: Your `reduce` call is missing the initial value being passed as the second argumnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `.reduce` here makes things too convoluted. Consider a plain loop where you increment the appropriate property an an object declared outside.

```js
const data = [
  { shoeSize: "size 10", total: 9},
  { shoeSize: "size 10", total: 3},
  { shoeSize: "size 5", total: 2}
];

const grandTotal = {};
for (const { shoeSize, total } of data) {
  const digits = shoeSize.match(/\d+/)[0];
  if (!digits) continue;
  const key = `shoeSize${digits}Total`;
  grandTotal[key] = (grandTotal[key] || 0) + total;
}
console.log(grandTotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

We could implement basic approaches using **EcmaScript Methods** such as [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Take a look at this code snippet, pal. I certainly hope this helps, buddy!

```js
const data = [
  { shoeSize: "size 10", total: 9 },
  { shoeSize: "size 10", total: 3 },
  { shoeSize: "size 5", total: 2 },
];

let shoeSize10Total = 0;
let shoeSize05Total = 0;

const grandTotal = (data) => {
  data.filter((el) => {
    if (el.shoeSize === "size 10") {
      shoeSize10Total += el.total;
    } else {
      shoeSize05Total += el.total;
    }
  });
  return { shoeSize10Total, shoeSize05Total };
};

console.log(grandTotal(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

One of issues is that you are not using the `initialValue` of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.
Moreover, the approach to build the `grandTotal` is far from the best as the values are hardcoded into the `reduce` handler, for multiple `size` values that code will be a mess.
A cleaner approach is to create a mapping of input values to output keys, then in the `reduce` handler just to use that mapping for lookups, like this:

```js
const data = [
  { shoeSize: "size 10", total: 9},
  { shoeSize: "size 10", total: 3},
  { shoeSize: "size 5", total: 2}
];

const map = {
  'size 5': 'shoeSize5Total',
  'size 10': 'shoeSize10Total'
};

const grandTotal = data.reduce((o, {shoeSize: s, total}) =>
  (o[map[s]] = (o[map[s]] ?? 0) + total, o), {});

console.log(grandTotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

little info about below code

firstly use `{}` object as initial value to reduce function

now extract shoeSize from data array and use it as a key for new object

now write a condition if that key exist in new object then increment the value otherwise create a new property to object

boom at the end you will have a sorted object as a result

```js
const data = [
    { shoeSize: "size 10", total: 9 },
    { shoeSize: "size 10", total: 3 },
    { shoeSize: "size 5", total: 2 }
]

let res = data.reduce((main,each)=>{
    let num = each.shoeSize.match(/\d+/)[0],
        newKey = `shoeSize${num}Total`,
        exist = typeof main[newKey] !== "undefined"
    if(exist){main[newKey] += each.total}
    else{main[newKey] = each.total}
    return main
},{})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple forEach will do:

```js
const data = [
{ shoeSize: "size 10", total: 9},
{ shoeSize: "size 10", total: 3},
{ shoeSize: "size 5", total: 2}
]

const n = {}
data.forEach(d => {
  
  const key = "Shoe" + d.shoeSize.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + d.shoeSize.slice(1).replace(" ","") + 'Total';
  const res = Object.keys(n).filter(_i => _i == key)

  if (res.length == 0) {
      n[key] = 0;    
  }
  n[key] += d.total;  
})


console.log(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `.reduce` is the right think to use in this problem because it makes things a little bit more complex in this situation. So I prefer always using functions to do the work for me.

```js
function collectShoesTogether(arr) {
  var obj = {};

  arr.forEach((item) => {
    let key = `shoeSize${item.shoeSize.split(" ").join("")}Total`;

    if (obj[key] === undefined) {
      obj[key] = item.total;
    } else {
      obj[key] += item.total;
    }
  });

  return obj;
}
```